# set TextView value for array

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I have make an application where I am swiping number of photos,I have added these photos in an array  and I want to get the simple numerical values(for example:-1,2,3 etc) for these items and for this I have used the for loop,and set these values to the textview and then dynamically adding these textview to the linearlayout and and then this linearlayout to the viewgroup container.
By doing this I am just able to show the last number value for an array item;below is my code.

```
LinearLayout linearlay=new LinearLayout(context);
linearlay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    imageView.setImageResource(image_id[position]);
    linearlay.addView(imageView,0);
    for(int i=0;i<image_id.length;i++)
    {
                  linearlay.removeView(textView);
          textView.setText("Image: "+(i+1));
          linearlay.addView(textView);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(linearlay);
    }
            return linearlay;
}   TextView textView=new TextView(context);
```

I want to setText value as 1,2,3... and show it in layout but only the last value is being shown.

Comment: Do you want to set Array item to your textview???

Comment: Use append instead of setText or move it outside for loop

Comment: yes. I am setting it using setText() method but only last value is being shown

Comment: @user2561559 `append` instead of `setText`. and also move  `linearlay.addView(textView);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(linearlay)` outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Do below three changes - 
1) Remove   linearlay.removeView(textView); from code.

It is deleting your last added textview

2) Also add append inplace of setText

3) Also put linearlay.addView(textView);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(linearlay);
outside loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
linearlay.addView(imageView,0);
textView=new TextView(context); // declare textview as a class member
linearlay.addView(textView); 
((ViewPager) container).addView(linearlay);
    for(int i=0;i<image_id.length;i++)
    {
          textView.append("Image: "+(i+1));

    }
    return linearlay;
}
```

Comment: with this I am getting the output on a single photo as:-Image 1,Image 2, Image 3.while I want to get the textview as output on single photo as Image 1,on swiping, the second photo the textview output shuold be Image 2.

Comment: @user2561559 then you don't need a for loop. when you swipe you need to set the value to textview.

Comment: this is what I am doing before too,and by doing this I am gettig the output Image 6 on each photo,Kindly tell me how to correct this thing.

Comment: @user2561559 check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html. especially this line `View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum)` which will show the current fragment page. I don't know what you are using. but the code snippets uses `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: @user2561559 you need to use the position param in your view pager adapter

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line outside for loop:

```
linearlay.removeView(textView);
```

Bcs, it is removing the textview everytime.